# Translating individual pieces of code to loop statement

Tags: matlab

I am working on matlab with a file composed of units requested in different days (orders of products). The file that can be found in the next link:[File](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wcnAFFc3Yo9PNGwZPbiVHdynqNinaz-8)

It has 4 columns. The second and fourth show the day and number of units respectively. This file has 3000 rows and I would like to do this task for all the entire rows in the file. The main task of the code I will show consist of filling column 6 with 1 every time the value calculated in column 5 is below 300. The column 5 shows the reduction of volume of units that initially is 1000. I will show with the next code:

```
clear
%Data
File='File.csv';
dataf=csvread(File, 1);
unbl=0;
dataf=[dataf zeros(size(dataf,1),1) zeros(size(dataf,1),1)];
%Loop by pieces
for i=1:size(dataf,1)
    if i==1
        dataf(i,5)=1000-dataf(i,4);
    else
        dataf(i,5)=dataf(i-1,5)-dataf(i,4);
    end
    if dataf(i,5)<300 && dataf(i-1,5)>=300
        dataf(i,6)=1;
    end
end
```

[image: I1]

In line 29, there is a value below 300 for column 5, therefore 1 in column 6. The number of day in column 2 is 3. Then I have to add 4 to this and find the row when this happens first. In this case the first 7. This code makes that and saves the value of column 5 in the previous row in `unlb`:

```
index =find(dataf(:,6)==1);
index2 = find(dataf(:,2)==dataf(index,2)+4,1);
unbl = unbl+dataf(index2-1,5);
```

In this row, I will have new stock then I have to add to the actual value of column 5 the quantity 1200:

```
dataf(index2,5) = 1200+dataf(index2,5);
```

I got this:

[image: I2]

Therefore, from this point I have to repeat the same task. I use this long code:

```
for j=(index2+1):size(dataf,1)
    dataf(j,5)=dataf(j-1,5)-dataf(j,4);
    if dataf(j,5)<300 && dataf(j-1,5)>=300
        dataf(j,6)=1;
    end
end

index =find(dataf(:,6)==1,1,'last');
index2 = find(dataf(:,2)==dataf(index,2)+4,1);
unbl = unbl+dataf(index2-1,5);
dataf(index2,5) = 1200+dataf(index2,5);

for k=(index2+1):size(dataf,1)
    dataf(k,5)=dataf(k-1,5)-dataf(k,4);
    if dataf(k,5)<300 && dataf(k-1,5)>=300
        dataf(k,6)=1;
    end
end

index =find(dataf(:,6)==1,1,'last');
index2 = find(dataf(:,2)==dataf(index,2)+4,1);
unbl = unbl+dataf(index2-1,5);
dataf(index2,5) = 1200+dataf(index2,5);

for l=(index2+1):size(dataf,1)
    dataf(l,5)=dataf(l-1,5)-dataf(l,4);
    if dataf(l,5)<300 && dataf(l-1,5)>=300
        dataf(l,6)=1;
    end
end

index =find(dataf(:,6)==1,1,'last');
index2 = find(dataf(:,2)==dataf(index,2)+4,1);
unbl = unbl+dataf(index2-1,5);
dataf(index2,5) = 1200+dataf(index2,5);
```

This code does the task for some remaining rows but if I have to complete the entire dataset it will be too large. I tried a one loop solution but unfortunately it does not work:

```
%One loop (not working)
index=0;
index2=0;
unbl=0;
for i=1:size(dataf,1)
    if i==1
        dataf(i,5)=1000-dataf(i,4);
    else
        dataf(i,5)=dataf(i-1,5)-dataf(i,4);
    end
    if dataf(i,5)<300 && dataf(i-1,5)>=300
        dataf(i,6)=1;
        index =find(dataf(:,6)==1);
        index2 = find(dataf(:,2)==dataf(index,2)+4,1);
    end
    unbl = unbl+dataf(index2-1,5);
    dataf(index2,5) = 1200+dataf(index2,5);
    i=index2+1;
end
```

I do not know how to update the index of the loop to move across all rows and get the cumulative value saved in `unbl`. Please could you help to fix this pieces of code into one loop statement to move around all rows and reproduce the task previously mentioned. Many Thanks.

Comment: not an answer: `[dataf zeros(size(dataf,1),1) zeros(size(dataf,1),1)]` = `[dataf zeros(size(dataf,1),2)]`

Comment: Not sure what you try to do, but this is certainly not valid: `i=index2+1` - you should not (and as far as I know can not) change the loop iterator inside a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a piece of code that I believe do what you need (explanations in the comments inside):

```
stock = 1000;
new_stock = 1200;
unbl = 0;
% culculate the comulative substraction from the initial stock:
temp = cumsum([stock; -dataf(:,4)]);
dataf(:,5) = temp(2:end); % no need for the first element (1000)
% find when to set a new order:
low_stock = find(dataf(:,5)<300,1);
% start the loop
last_low = 0;
while low_stock~=last_low % if you found a new date with low stock
    last_low = low_stock; % use the new date
    dataf(last_low,6) = 1; % place 1 in the date with low stock
    % find the first line 4 days ahead:
    refill = last_low+find(dataf(last_low:end,2)==dataf(last_low,2)+4,1)-1;
    % add the amount on column 5 in the row above ind_b to 'unbl'
    unbl = unbl+dataf(refill-1,5);
    % add new stock to all rows below after stock arival
    dataf(refill:end,5) = dataf(refill:end,5)+new_stock;
    % find the next time to set a new order:
    low_stock = refill+find(dataf(refill+1:end,5)<300,1);    
end
```

Comment: Many thanks dear @EBH but I want to iterate for all rows in this structure of data. I put different pieces of code showing the connection. Could you please help me with a way to do this for all rows?

Comment: @Duck, this **will** go through all the line in the file, that's why I use a `while` loop. I suggest that you first try it and see if you get the correct result. Then, if not, explain what was wrong, and try to explain better *what* the code should do, and not *how* it should do that.

Comment: actually @EBH it saves the one in column 6 but the value in column 5 is not updated. Is there any way we can chat? It is a inventory problem so each time column 5 is less than 300 I need to know the day (1 in column 6) and in that day I ask for stock that arrives after 4 days an I add this to the actual value in that row in column 5. How could I fix this?

Comment: 1. Have you noticed I updated the answer? 2. Look at this line `dataf(ind_b:end,5) = dataf(ind_b:end,5)+1200` this is the only case where column 5 is updated (after the first assignment) - when the stock arrives, do you see it happens at least ones?

Comment: yes @EBH I see and actually is getting updated but I am getting all elements empty with your new solution. The problem is next: You have an initial stock of 1000 so orders arrive each day (column 4) and you have to reduce this stock. When the value after reducing each order is less than 300 you set a new order that arrives in 4 days (I do this by looking for the day that stock is < 300 and sum 4). In 4 days new stock arrives and you add 1200 units to the value in that day (day of arriving). Maybe it is clear in this way.

Comment: Well, I don't understand how could you get empty elements, as none of the code lines is deleting anything. However, I have updated the answer with more useful comments based on your explanation and changed the variables names as well. I run this code on a demo data I created and get something the looks fine: `N = 500;
dataf = zeros(N,6);
dataf(:,2) = repelem(1:N/5,5);
dataf(:,4) = randi(30,[N,1]);` try it and see if you get what you expected.

Comment: Dear @EBH thanks for your answer but I still get for example the value of `unbl` empty. I do not what is happening. Please could you help me to solve this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184220/discussion-between-duck-and-ebh).